# Why did Season 7, Episode 3 of "Hawaii Five-O" use a Hillsong United song?

Tags: hawaii-five-0

Towards the end of Season 7, Episode 3 of *Hawaii Five-O*, Kono and Rosey (a former competitor of Kono's who was injured in Iraq) go surfing together. The background music is "Touch the Sky" by Hillsong United. Is it known who chose that song and why? Why do they use an explicitly religious song on a show with no discernable religious themes?

Comment: to answer **Who** , probably the producing/writing crew.. and **Why** could be because that song suited for the situation.

Comment: @Vishwa The song in question is *explicitly* religious, which seems odd for a show with no discernable religious themes. Why?

Comment: It depends, while as a whole, show may not carry out a religious aspects, but it generally supports and appreciates hawaiian culture along with everything including beliefs, tradition and customs.. So as I've said earlier, it depends on the scene.. On the scene that song was playing, It should have some connection with the incidents/activities being carried out.  **I don't remember everything in the scene, but song may've been used to illustrate hope and belief in god for Rosey**

Comment: @Vishwa As far as I know, though, the main reason you would even know about Hillsong United would be if you follow Contemporary Christian Music... I'm just curious how they even came to be familiar with that material in the first place.

Comment: You ain't getting anything I'm saying.. **It depends on the scene**. If  the scene needed to inspire some religious expression, they use music in that category, if scene needed suspense, they use suspense music.. I don't get how your obsession with the band become an issue here..

Comment: @Visha Why are you arguing around in comments instead of putting all that into a proper answer?

Comment: @Vishwa No, I understand that - I'm just wondering how they even knew about the band in the first place (which is part of the question). Does someone on their staff follow Contemporary Christian Music?

Comment: If your question is **how they even knew about the band**, then it's falling into off-topic category

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Wasn't sure what I gathered properly suited for an answer, anyway, I've put together few lines from my comments as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In brief...**

*It depends on the scene/situation.*

To answer **Who** , 
probably the producing/writing crew..

and **Why**,

because that song suited for the situation.

---

Answering with bit of a details for your question **Why do they use an explicitly religious song on a show with no discernable religious themes**,

It depends, while as a whole, show may not carry out a religious aspects, but it generally supports and appreciates hawaiian culture along with everything including beliefs, tradition and customs..

So as I've said earlier, it depends on the scene..

On the scene that song was playing, It should have some connection with the incidents/activities being carried out. I don't remember everything in the scene, but song may've been used to illustrate hope and belief in god for Rosey.

**P.S**
If your question is **how they even knew about the band in the first place?**, then it's *probably* falling into off-topic category. We don't know for the moment. Cannot find any official statements regarding this